# iphone mapview current location

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

I'm able to show current location on mapview. It shows round blue color circle. When I click on the circle, it shows "Current Location".
I want to show users current location as green pin. on click of pin, i want to show "My Location" annotation. How to do it. 
Please suggest me how to do it.

Comment: Hi, any link where I can find the tutorial of above mentioned work. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Doing so is a bad idea. The blue dot and associated animation is a convention that is adhered to by all MapKit apps. Your user might be moving too. A pin is associated with a fixed location. Someone holding a phone is not a fixed point.

Please really think about the MapKit standards and Apple HIG they are there to help your users understand and enjoy your app.